# Error using array and node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, foreach

I am new in TikZ and I am trying to make a graph with 12 nodes in a ring shape.

My code below is not working:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {12}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] (teste[\s]) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {};
}

\foreach \s in {1,...,9}
{
  \pgfmathparse{\s+1}
  \draw (teste[\s]) -- (teste[\pgfmathresult]);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got an example here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/ and I changed some things.

The error showed is :

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named teste[2 is known.See the pgf package
documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... }

! Package pgf Error: No shape named teste[3 is known.See the pgf package
documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... }

... and so on ...

! Package pgf Error: No shape named teste[10 is known.See the pgf package
documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... }
```

What is wrong in my code? How can I make this array work like other programming languages?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a good solution, but I'm pretty sure that the issue is that `\pgfmathresult` yields something like `2.0`, so the coordinate is interpreted as anchor `0]` of node `teste[2`.

Comment: You can use `\pgfmathparse{int(\s+1)}` so that `\pgfmathresult` is a plain integer without a decimal point.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of converting `reals` into `integers`, you can use already defined like `int` values through `count` option.

Also for cycling joins you can use `remember` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {12}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s [count=\ns] in {1,...,\n}
  \node[draw, circle] (teste-\ns) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {};

\foreach \s [remember=\s as \next (initially \n)] in {1,...,12}
  \draw (teste-\next) -- (teste-\s);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]